# Weakly Harmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Theorem: Let $u\in L_{loc}^1(\Omega)$ weakly harmonic. Then $u\in C^\infty$ and $\Delta u=0$.

The author uses the following argument:

He first show that if u is weakly harmonic the the spherical mean

$\frac{1}{|\partial B_r|}\int_{\partial B_r(y)}u(x)dS(x)$

is constant in $r<dist(y,\partial \Omega)$. Then he uses this result

Theorem*: Let $u\in L^1_{loc}$ and suppose $u(x)=\frac{1}{|\partial B_r|}\int_{\partial B_r}u(y)dS(Y)$ for $x\in\Omega$ and $r<dist(x,\partial\Omega)$ then $u\inC^\infty(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u=0$ in the classic sense.

My question is, how the fact of the mean being constant alow me to use Theorem*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$ r \mapsto \frac 1{\vert \partial B_r \vert }\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y ) \, dS(y)$$ is constant then  $$\frac 1{\vert \partial B_r \vert }\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y ) \, dS(y) =\lim_{r \to 0^+}\frac 1{\vert \partial B_r \vert }\int_{\partial B_r(x)} u(y ) \, dS(y) =u(x).  $$